# How can I customize the Windows "drag" and "copy" mouse cursor?

Tags: windows, mouse-cursor

When dragging or copying items (with the mouse) in different programs, Windows displays a specific mouse cursor. How can I change this cursor? It's not possible through the standard "Mouse" control panel.

Comment: There is no Windows-specific "dragging" mouse cursor.  You say "in different programs"; can you give an example, and a screenshot of the cursor you're talking about? It may be application specific.

Comment: I can't easily capture the mouse cursor. I'm specifically referring to the drag cursor when dragging a file in Explorer. It's a standard mouse pointer with a selection-box or a plus sign next to it. If you try it out, you'll see what I mean. It seems that this would be a standard Windows cursor but if it's built into Explorer itself then there won't be a way to change it. These cursors I'm talking about, are not present in the c:\windows\cursors directory.

Comment: If its built into Windows Explorer that means, the only way to change the icon, would be if you replaced Windows Explorer.